# iText and interactive barcodes

Tags: itext, barcode, pdf417

I have a bunch of PDF forms with barcodes, which are generated from what the user fills in.
I would like to be able to change the barcode behavior and came across iText. But the examples for Barcodes seem to build static Barcodes (like an image).
Does iText also have interactive PDF barcodes? Or any other libary?

Answer (score 0):

Yes itext 7 do have library that can handle barcodes and QR codes.

```
public void processEnd(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
//Transform barcode into image
qrCodeAsImage = new Image(qrCode.createFormXObject(context.getPdfDocument()));
}
```

You can implement customize the TagWorker class as per your need.